# How set static route in RHEL 8 with Ansible?

Tags: ansible, rhel

I have a requirement to maintain a list of static routes across many RHEL 8 VMs (~100) and thinking of managing this with Ansible.

Tried several methods suggested for different scenarios and still no luck.

Some options I tried were,

1. `net_static_route` - Which is obviously for network appliances
2. `linux-system-roles.network` ([Redhat Doc](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/administration_and_configuration_tasks_using_system_roles_in_rhel/using-system-roles-to-configure-network-connections_administration-and-configuration-tasks-using-system-roles-in-rhel))

In my case, I dont want to disturb any network interface which are actively being used.

Just want to add a static route to send the traffic via a different interface, not through default route.

Command I use to do this manually is like,

```
#sudo ip route add 192.168.1.2 via 192.168.100.1 dev ens224 proto static metric 100
```

Anyone has done something like this?

Answer (score 1):

In RHEL 8 you can [use the `nmcli` command to configure a static route](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/configuring-static-routes_configuring-and-managing-networking). For this the Ansible [nmcli_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/nmcli_module.html) is available and with which you can configure the interfaces.